# removing time from date string

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

have a few dates in a file (eg. 2021-06-15)
wrote a code to convert them from string to datetime format

```
x = str(line[-1])
            dates = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
            print(dates)
```

but the result is 2021-06-15 00:00:00
how do I remove the time part?

Answer (score 1):

add on the `.date()` method

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '2021-06-01'

dates = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(dates)
```

**Output with time:**

```
dates = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(dates)

2021-06-01 00:00:00
```

**Output without time:**

```
dates = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(dates)

2021-06-01
```

Answer (score 0):

If yo want date only, try this

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Here `x` is the time you specify